# Show that the area of a trapezoid is given in function of one of its angles by $f(x)=4\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> [image]
>
> The picture represents an isosceles trapezoid [ABCD]. The sides [AD]
>   and [BC] are parallell. It is also known that:
>
> - $\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}=\overline{CD}=2$
> - $\alpha$ is the angle of $ABC$ and $\alpha \in ]\pi/3;\pi/2]$
>
> Consider the function f defined by:
>
> $$f(x) = 4\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))$$
>
> Show that for each $\alpha \in ]\pi/3;\pi/2]$, the area of the
>   trapezoid is $f(\alpha)$.

I messed with the picture a bit and did this:

[image]

So the area of [ABCD] is given by

$$2 \cdot A_{\text{smaller trapezoid}}$$

The area of the smaller trapezoid is given by:

$$\frac{1+b}{2}\cdot 2\tan(\alpha)$$

To find b I did:

[image]

$$2^2 = a^2+(2\tan(\alpha))^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
4 = a^2+4\tan(\alpha)^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
a = \sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2}$$

$b = 1- \sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2}$

So the formula becomes:

$$A_{[ABCD]} = 2\cdot (\frac{1+1- \sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2}}{2} \cdot 2\tan(\alpha)) = \\
2\cdot ((2-\sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2})\tan(\alpha)) = \\
2\cdot (2\tan(\alpha)-\tan(\alpha)\sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2}) = \\
4\tan(\alpha)-2\tan(\alpha)\sqrt{4-4\tan(\alpha)^2} = \\
4\tan(\alpha)-\sqrt{4\tan(\alpha)^2(4-4\tan(\alpha)^2)} = \\
4\tan(\alpha)-\sqrt{16\tan^2(\alpha)-16\tan^4(\alpha)}$$

I put this expression and the one given by my book in the calculator to see if they would coincide but they don't. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical in these figures:

[image]
[image]

Should be $2 \sin \alpha.$

$a =  2 \cos\alpha\\
b = 1-a\\
\frac 12 (B+b) = \frac 12(1+1-2\cos \alpha) = 1-\cos \alpha\\
A = 2(\frac 12 (B+b))(2 \sin \alpha) = 4\sin\alpha(1-\cos\alpha)$

Comment: Why isn't the height $2\tan(\alpha)$?

Comment: I think the question should be, "why would it be?"  I think the simplest explanation is: Opposite / Hypotenuse = $\sin x,$  Opposite / Adjacent = $\tan x.$  Which data do you have?

Comment: Right, I get it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i would compute $$A=\frac{2+a}{2}h$$ with $$a=AD$$ and $$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{h}{x}$$ with $$2x+a=2$$ can you finish?

Comment: What did I do wrong though? Isn't $h = 2\tan(\alpha)$?